# Access a sharepoint site via local machine

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need to access to a SharePoint site "//employee/site" via my local machine.
I added the IP address of the server & URl to the host file of my local machine.
but I still have  404

Comment: 404 is page not found . Which error are you getting unauthorized or page not found?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you need to [disable the loopback check for IIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us). If this is a dev server, I'd follow the second option.

1. To set the DisableLoopbackCheck registry key, follow these steps:
   Set the `DisableStrictNameChecking` registry entry to 1.
2. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
3. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`
4. Right-click `Lsa`, point to New, and then click `DWORD` Value.
5. Type `DisableLoopbackCheck`, and then press ENTER.
6. Right-click `DisableLoopbackCheck`, and then click Modify.
7. In the `Value data` box, type 1, and then click OK.
8. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart your computer.